# Laravel routing nor working (PLESK)

Tags: php, laravel, plesk

I am using Laravel as a Plesk Website on a Centos7 server.The Home Page is working but when I open the Login or Register Page i get a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable Page.

Apache Log:

```
 2017-10-01 12:05:21    Error   146.0.128.255   503 GET /login HTTP/1.0     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36 1.18 K  Apache access
2017-10-01 12:05:21 Error           (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /var/www/vhosts/system/pif.xanlosh.us/php-fpm.sock (*) failed             Apache error
2017-10-01 12:05:21 Error   146.0.128.255       AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

Thanks in advance

Solved: I switched from FPM to Fastcgi and its working now.

Comment: Is the Apache mod_rewrite enabled ?

Comment: rewrite is enabled in plesk